# Surefire is going to kill self fork JVM. The exit has elapsed 30 seconds after System.exit(0)

Tags: java, maven, process, processbuilder, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using **maven surefire plugin** (LTS Version) to execute tests on two testing frameworks (e.g, jUnit, jBehave).

Have tried to implement parallelisation by spawning couple of Threads which in turn create processes to execute surefire jar, taking it from -

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getSystemProperties().get("sun.java.command")
```

Code snippet to show process creation -
**CustomRunner.java**

```
  void run() {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commandArray);
    Map<String, String> environment = processBuilder.environment();
    environment.put("platformIndex", String.valueOf(platformIndex));
    try {
        processBuilder.inheritIO();
        Process p = processBuilder.start();
        LOGGER.info("Is Alive {} {}", p.isAlive(), LocalTime.now());
        int statusCode = p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EntryPoint.java**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   Thread thread = new Thread(new CustomRunner(commandArray, String.valueOf(i)));
   thread.start();
   threadList.add(thread);
 }
threadList.forEach(thread -> {
   try {
     thread.join();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
});
    
System.exit(exitcode);
```

After running two or sometimes three processes in corresponding Threads, the process execution got stuck on p.waitFor();

Then the process exits after 30 secs and with error message **"Surefire is going to kill self fork JVM. The exit has elapsed 30 seconds after System.exit(0)."** resulting in Build Failure (sometimes it doesn't) though the tests have passed in their respective processes.

Seems like surefire execution is stuck in some processes. Could you please let me know what can be the possible reasons for it and how to mitigate this? Tried extending the **ForkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds** to few minutes but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what: ` maven surefire plugin (LTS Version)` this means? Which version of maven-surefire-plugin do you use ?

Comment: Using Latest Version i.e. 3.0.0-M7

Comment: Ok. But what exactly happened? Show log file output of the failing tests also full test code also your pom file ...best would be an example project on github or alike?

Comment: Hey, Tests are not failing at all. It's just that, child processes are not getting spawned. Updated the description with full code.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error message using 3.0.0-M7.  It appears to happen right about the 30 second mark when running the set of JUnit tests for child module.  Tried setting the Maven property `surefire.timeout=90` but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/shutdown.html#embedded-shutdown) after all daemon processes are closed, surefire waits for non daemon processes to be closed, but only for 30s. It seems like you are creating non daemon thread (non-daemon threads spawn other non-daemon). I assume you have two options:

1. Increase surefire exit timeout with either `surefire.exitTimeout` property or  `<forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds>` property in plugin configuration.
2. Make your thread a daemon, i.e. `thread.setDaemon(true);`